# G5 signed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, paypal, https, paypal-ipn

I recently added SSL to my site (www.uberwriteronline.com) and my PayPal IPN stopped working.  I learned that my SSL cert didn't meet PayPal's standards.  https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US

I had a SHA-2 certificate, but it was being signed by a GoDaddy G2 root certificate.  I'm not clear on how to regenerate the CSR using the G5 root certificate.  I installed the G5 root certificate on my machine from https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5624 but when I regenerate the CSR it still points to G2.  Sorry for the noob question, but how to I get this to use the G5 root?

Comment: What is the URL of your site? Doesn't have to be the IPN address, just the root URL. This way we can check the SSL config.

Comment: CSR is a request that is sent to your certificate provider. Just regenerating it won't do anything for you. If the certificate you're getting isn't issued against the right root, talk to your certificate provider.

Comment: Also, site setup issues like this are a better fit for serverfault.com.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that is helpful.  Your comment was confirmed by GoDaddy that they only offer G2 root certs right now.  Can you recommend a cert provider?